# Query same field from two different tables MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been having an issue trying to query 3 tables and 2 with the same field. Using php and mysql

example

TableA
TableB
TableC

keyword in the query would be a search term.

```
SELECT 
   title 
FROM TableA as A 
LEFT JOIN TableC as C 
   ON TableA.id=TableC.id 
WHERE 1 
   AND TableC.private='0' 
   AND ( 
        title LIKE '".$keyword."%' 
     OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
     OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."' 
     OR title = '".$keyword."' 
   )
```

The problem I'm having is I ALSO need to simultaneously search TableB for title and do a match based on the same keyword. How do I incorporate TableB title field into the query?

So if there is say TableA with title=America and TableB with title=American it will display both results from both tables since it would match the LIKE query.

Then with PHP show the result. If TableA or TableB matches show that result(s). And loop through the array etc.

It has to be in a query because I'm using it for a search parameter.

TIA

Comment: Please go and read about [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and prepared statement. And buy/steal yourself [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book.

Comment: @tereško I'll have to look into more SQL tutorials. I needed more help with that not as much PHP. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a union:

```
SELECT title FROM TableA as A LEFT JOIN TableC as C ON TableA.id=TableC.id WHERE 1 AND TABLEC.private='0' AND ( title LIKE '".$keyword."%' OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
             OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."' OR title = '".$keyword."' )
UNION
SELECT title FROM TableB as B LEFT JOIN TableC as C ON TableB.id=TableC.id WHERE 1 AND TABLEC.private='0' AND ( title LIKE '".$keyword."%' OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."%' 
             OR title LIKE '%".$keyword."' OR title = '".$keyword."' )
```

Comment: Ok, I thought unions had to have the same columns in the tables. I'll try it.

Comment: Oh yeah that won't work because TableB does not have the ID table that TableA does. So I can't do the same query. They are not identical tables. Say one table is table for songs and the other is a table for favorites. Both have the title field and can have different data. If there is a match I want it to show the song title or favorite title or however many matches there are.

Comment: Each query in the union must have the same number of columns, with the same datatype for each corresponding column.  Everything else is valid.

Comment: So you will have to modify the query on TableB as needed, but that should still work.

Comment: Thanks I think that did it. I've never used Unions before, mostly joins but that is really helpful. It got what I needed. Awesome.